# Best way to compare ASCII value

Tags: c, compare, ascii

Hey guys I just started taking c classes and I had a question about comparing the ASCII values in C.

Let's say I have the word "hello" and I want to check if "h" in the ASCII table matches 104, normally it would. So I'm using the following piece of code to do so, although I seem to find this method not really efficient. So I'm wondering if there are other ways.

```
char word [] = "hello";
if (("%d", word[0]) == 104) puts("Yay");
```

Sorry if it's a dumb question, but just didn't seem so efficient in my eyes.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: The part I find inefficient is:

```
("%d", word[0])
```

Comment: I've never seen that before and I've been using C a long time. That doesn't mean much though. You can use `word[0]=='h'`

Comment: @krowe answered you question, so just a note: always wrap your conditional blocks with curly braces even if you only have one statement in it ... yet.

Comment: @fejese Ok I'll remember that, is there any particular reason why I should avoid using the likes of "puts"? I have a Java background so I was used to the conditional blocks but the likes of "puts" was something new and that's why I started using them.

Comment: @Glenndisimo: Who said you should avoid puts? It´s (one possible) equivalent to Java´s System.out.println

Comment: @Glenndisimo What I was saying is that instead of `if (word[0] == 104) puts("Yay");` you should write `if (word[0] == 104) { puts("Yay"); }` (notice the curly braces). This is to avoid issues later if you'd add statements later or just accidentally duplicate a line (see the "What was the bug?" section in this article for a very good example: http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/feb/25/apples-ssl-iphone-vulnerability-how-did-it-happen-and-what-next)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly compare `char` and `int` types in C, so the following code:

```
char word[]  = "hello";
if(word[0] == 104) puts("Yay");
```

If equivalent to your snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Your `("%d", word[0])` looks like a `printf` call that's missing the `printf`. But since you're not calling a function, it's really nothing like that at all. It's just a comma operator, which evaluates the left argument (`"%d"`), throws the result away, and uses the right argument.

`"%d"` is an expression without side effects, so evaluating it does exactly nothing.

Your test can be shortened to `if(word[0] == 104)` which does the same thing. Or even better, shorten it to `if(word[0] == 'h')` which is still the same but readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
char word [] = "hello";
if (("%d", word[0]) == 104) puts("Yay");
```

Equivalent code would be:

```
if('h' == 104) puts("Yay");
```

And final transform:

```
puts("Yay");
```

- If you use multiple expressions separated by a comma, they are evaluated in order and the last one determines the result.
- Also, you can directly use character constants like in my answer. Just beware of multi-character-constants, which are legal but not portable and thus nor really useful.
- Next, even without optimizations enabled, most compilers do a creditable job at constant folding, so it's not inefficient.
- Last, those constants are used to remove control structures if possible.